# jQuery if statement to show different charts on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, href

I have a series of buttons - when clicked I need a different chart to generate. Although the module (HTML/CSS) appears on click, the charts do not. The charts work in another part of the app, so I am sure that code is good to go and did not add to this post.

HTML:

```
<a href="#{{name-id}}" aria-controls="{{name-id}}" data-toggle="pill" 
id='nameType'>{{name-id}}</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
if ($('#nameType').attr('href') == 'XYZ'){
    var treeData = treeXYZ;
}else{
    var treeData = treeABC;
}
```

Comment: What do `treeXYZ` and `treeABC` correspond to in you HTML ?

Comment: You should declare 'treeData' once and keep on setting the value.

Comment: You haven't added enough information to make this question answerable by SO users. Please read the advice on [how to write a good question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

You're just storing data to variables, and not using them.

You should do something like this:

```
var treeData;
if ($('#nameType').attr('href') == 'XYZ'){
  treeData = treeXYZ;
}else{
  treeData = treeABC;
}
$('#nameType').prop('href', treeData)
```